# Mapping functions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list, mapping

I am trying to create two functions, such that:

```
x(0) = [] # (0 maps to the empty list)
```

and

```
x(n+1) = [x(n),[x(n)]] # (n+1 maps to the list that contains x(n) and singleton x(n))
```

The function only needs to accept non-negative integers.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with one function using recursion - if i is 0 then we return the base case, otherwise we recurse and return the function as described in the question.

```
def x(i):
    if i == 0:
        return []
    r = x(i-1)
    return [r, [r]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are fan of lambdas or at least you like obscure oneliners, you also could use this :D

```py
x = (lambda i: (lambda f, i: f(f, i))((lambda f, i: ([f(f, i-1), [f(f, i-1)]] if i > 0 else [])), i))
```